# Detect memory leak in windows

Tags: c#, c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have written a small c# console application to check the c# Dll which is wrapper of native c++ dll. In c# application i am just doing crypto operation in loop to check memory consumption. I am getting memory leak since after 15 minute to run the application memory goes up to 5GB. means there is some memory leakage.

[image]

In first view, it seems there is some memory issue in native c++ dll, So I checked with valgrind in linux environment. But didn't get any memory leak in linux environment.

So I am trying to check memory consumption in windows platform through GFlags and UMDH (Windgb tools).
Is there any other approach we can follow.

Comment: You can use performance counters, ETW events or any memory profiler

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleaker? It seems to be a good substitute for valgrind. Alternatively you can install valgrind in Windows using Linux subsystem.

https://www.albertgao.xyz/2016/09/28/how-to-use-valgrind-on-windows/

https://www.deleaker.com/